# docker-compose .env vs direnv .envrc

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, direnv

We've been using [direnv](https://direnv.net) for quite some time now to automatically load environment variables in a specific folder. And since version 3, docker-compose seems to [support .env files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option).

The `.envrc` files used by direnv use `export`:

`export NODE_ENV=development`

Using the same file with docker-compose doesn't seem to work, only without `export` I get the value for the variable.

`NODE_ENV=development`

Any ideas on how to unify this into a single `.env` or `.envrc` file or an alternative to direnv?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution based on the comment chain for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48559138/1426788)

[direnv ships with a stdlib](https://direnv.net/man/direnv-stdlib.1.html) that can be used to support classical 'dotenv' settings

```
# myproject/.envrc - name of current file

# Usage: 
# dotenv <optionalPathToDotEnvFile> or defaults to .env
dotenv
```

```
# myproject/.env
FOO=BAR
```

this is especially helpful when using container systems like docker that support the dotenv style

Answer (score 10):

2022 update: direnv [now supports](https://github.com/direnv/direnv/blob/master/man/direnv.toml.1.md#load_dotenv) `.env` files in addition to `.envrc` files.

Enable it like so:

`$HOME/.config/direnv/direnv.toml`

```sh
[global]
load_dotenv = true
```

Comment: Thank you for this. The description for this option is here: https://direnv.net/man/direnv.toml.1.html#codeloaddotenvcode . I have proposed some changes here to make `load_dotenv` more clearer here:https://github.com/direnv/direnv/pull/1099

Answer (score 9):

I use the following setup to have variables available during dev from `.envrc` but using a `docker-compose` file for deployment:

In `./secrets` define your variables as docker-compose needs them (without export):

```
foo=bar
secret_var=secret
...
```

In `./envrc` export them to your shell:

```
#!bash
set -a
. ./secrets
set +a
```

`set -a` makes everything export by default, `set +a` turns this off afterwards.

Comment: Another way to do this is to use the `dotenv` function in the `.envrc`. That is part of the direnv stdlib.

Comment: There is not much documentation on this, so refer to the discussion here: https://github.com/direnv/direnv/issues/284#issuecomment-315275436
it's really as simple as having `dotenv` in the `.envrc` file.

Comment: the direnv stdlib can be found here https://direnv.net/man/direnv-stdlib.1.html